# Logging out with Satellizer.js

Tags: angularjs, node.js, satellizer

I figured out a problem if someone can help me. I am using Satellizer to do logins, and I am able to sign in correctly with google, and I have a token to use. But when I'm going to sign-out, the token does get deleted but I'm not completely signed out of Google. For example, I open up Youtube.com (not signed in), I will now sign in on my website using satellizer with Google. I get the OK, now I'm signed in on my website, I go back to Youtube, refresh, I'm now signed in on Youtube with the email I signed in on my website. When I logout out of from my website using $auth.logout();(method in satellizer to delete token) the token does get removed. But I remain signed into Youtube. anyone have any ideas why and how to fix?? I don't know what code to put, but I'll put up whatever is needed.
Thank you in advance

PS, I'm using node
for reference here's the github for satellizer [link](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/)

Comment: hello, steven, would you please tell me how can i get it up and running on localhost? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

@steven That's nothing to do with satellizer. Once you log into your app with satellizer it only takes permission from google to access your information and creates a token based on that for the backend to extract information using OAuth apis. 
You get signed in into youtube because you have your google account logged in. Even if you don't sign in to your app and simply sign in to your google account, you will be automatically signed into youtube. 
Visit this link for more information 
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/69961?hl=en